# Why does Lucene MatchAllDocsQuery "*:* AND name:a" and hibernate search deliver wrong results?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have a Spring Boot Application with Hibernate Search.

My database contains 2 entries:

*User a with name=a and user b with name=b.*

<s>When I search for `*:* AND NOT name:a` everything works fine and I get *user b*.</s> (Updated: this never worked.)

When I search for `*:* AND name:a` I get both *user a* and *user b* (in fact all elements in db). The strange thing is that `*:* AND name:b` returns *user b* like expected!
The same thing happens when I filter for other attributes like *streetname*. Whenever I search for `*:* AND xxxx:a` I get all entries.

Can anyone explain why?

That is how I search

```
Analyzer analyzer = ftEm.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer(Contact.class);
QueryParser parser = new LuceneQueryParser("description", analyzer, List.of("key"), List.of("startTime"));
Query luceneQuery = parser.parse("*:* AND streetname:a");
ftEm.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Contact.class).getResultList();
```

The `Contact` class is annotated with

```
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "sortTextAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = { @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class,
                        params = { @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "('-&\\.,\\(\\))"),
                                @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
                                @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all") }),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class,
                        params = { @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^0-9\\p{L} ])"),
                                @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
                                @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all") }),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = TrimFilterFactory.class) })
```

Comment: I'm guessing `a` and `b` are not *really* what you searched for. Please give the actual indexed data, the actual search parameters, and the code you used to build the query.

Comment: Thanks, @yrodiere. In fact the error only occurs when I search for `a`. The reported error is that searching for `name:a` does not work. My first guess was searching for a single character does not work, but for `b` it works. I added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `LuceneQueryParser` is; it must be a custom class of yours. I'll assume it does its job right.

I'm guessing you didn't assign a specific analyzer to the field `streetname`? `@AnalyzerDef` is just that: a definition. On its own, it has no effect on your mapping. You also need to assign the analyzer to a specific field, e.g.:

```
@Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "sortTextAnalyzer"))
private String streetname;
```

Failing that, Hibernate Search 5 will default to the `StandardAnalyzer`. One particularity of the `StandardAnalyzer` (in Hibernate Search 5 / Lucene 5) is that it removes common english "stopwords" from the text during analysis. Stopwords are very common words with little meaning: "the", "that", "for", ... and, you guessed it, "a".

So essentially, what I think is happening is that your argument "a" is getting analyzed using the `StandardAnalyzer`, leading to the strange behavior.
I can't say why `*:* AND NOT name:a` returns document `b`; I'd expect it to return nothing at all. Maybe it's because `name:a` gets translated to `name is empty`, which only document `a` will match? Maybe it's related to your implementation of `LuceneQueryParser`? Maybe you actually assigned an analyzer to field `name`, and it's not *exactly* the same as `StandardAnalyzer`?

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution. The same error occurs with `name:is` and `name:the`. I did not consider that *a* is a word but only saw it as single character!
(btw. `LuceneQueryParser` is nothing else than `QueryParser`)

Comment: I updated my question. I guess `*:* AND NOT name:a` never worked. But I would expect `*:* AND name:a` return zero elements instead of all...

Comment: Rightly so. But well... the Lucene query parsers are very low-level. You might have more luck with the Search DSL included in Hibernate Search. At the very least I'm sure that's how it behaves in Hibernate Search 6. You can [give Hibernate Search 6 it a try](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started): it's still in beta, but it has all but the most exotic features of Search 5, and has better test coverage when it comes to the search DSL.